# 19.10 uses more RAM and CPU compared to 19.04 with Chrome and Chromium Browser

Tags: desktop-environments, browser, 19.10

I just upgraded Ubuntu 19.10 from 19.04 and system is hanging while using Google-Chrome and Chromium and Firefox as well.

Is there anything that I can check or uninstall to reduce RAM & CPU usage?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's and Chromium's extensions each have their own process, consuming RAM and CPU time. Try removing every extension from those browsers.

If the problem persists, consider changing from Ubuntu's GNOME desktop to [LXQt](https://www.pcsuggest.com/install-lxqt-ubuntu-linux-mint/) or [XFCE](https://itsfoss.com/install-xfce-desktop-xubuntu/). Both are faster and use less RAM.

Comment: I tried the solution by removing Extentions but the problem still exist, so I increased the RAM from 4 GB to 8 GB and problem resolved but is there any solution so that we can reduce the RAM usage by Gnome Desktop, I don't want to change the Desktop.

Comment: Do a web search on "GNOME desktop memory use" and you'll see why. XFCE is more GNOME-like than LXQt. Also see http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2017/10/reducing-ubuntu-1710-memory-usage-down-to-600mib.html and https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/ways-to-reduce-ram-usage-on-linux/